# Can I get a race condition on Azure table insert operation?

Tags: azure, concurrency, azure-table-storage, azure-tablequery

I have a Function app that inserts some data into a Azure table. Is it possible that I will get a race condition and end up inserting data with the same ID twice, or does Azure make the Insert operations under some table level lock that would ensure I can't insert the same thing twice? The duplicate fields would be the partition key and row key.

In my case, I need to insert if row does not already exists, and read if it exists. In my Function app, I try to read before writing, but it is possible that another instance does a write op with same key in the meantime. If inserts are serialized, I could then fall back to reading when Insert command fails.

Answer (score 1):

> Is it possible that I will get a race condition and end up inserting
>   data with the same ID twice, or does Azure make the Insert operations
>   under some table level lock that would ensure I can't insert the same
>   thing twice?

It is certainly possible to get a race condition however having duplicate entries is not possible i.e for one PartitionKey/RowKey combination, there can be only one entity in a table.

> In my case, I need to insert if row does not already exists, and read
>   if it exists.

Assuming you're using .Net SDK, one way to achieve this would be to insert the entity using [`TableOperation.Insert`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.table.tableoperation.insert?view=azure-dotnet) and catch the exception. If the entity already exists, then you will get a `Conflict (409)` error. When you get this error, you can implement the logic of reading the entity.

Comment: And if it succeeded, then that is the row in the table now :)

Comment: That was the plan if I could guarantee that each INSERT is a atomic transaction :)

Comment: Could you tell me if there's any official doc that says the above? Or if you worked on Azure team, would have been helpful haha